# Counter value is not increasing, value remains constant in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, counter, increment

why does my variable **pc_score** and **my_score** not increase?  The output is 0.
I have two more functions of the eventListener format that I omitted from the code, but it should not affect the results. .
 I edited the post for runnable code. Thank you. 
Thanks for looking at my question.

```
<script>

    var options = ['rock','paper','scissors']
    let my_score = 0; 
    var pc_score = 0; 

    let computerChoice ;


    function computerSelection() {

         computerChoice = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)]
         return computerChoice;

    }


    var results = document.getElementById("result")
    document.getElementById("rock").addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        playerChoice=rock;
        computerSelection();
        if (computerChoice=='rock'){
             results.innerHTML="It is a tie";
        } else if (computerChoice=='paper'){
            results.innerHTML="It is a loss";
                 pc_score += 1;
        }else if (computerChoice=='scissors'){
            results.innerHTML="It is a win";
            my_score+= 1
        }

})

     const you = document.getElementById("You")
        you.innerHTML= my_score
    const computer = document.getElementById("Computer")
        computer.innerHTML=pc_score

  </script>
```

Comment: `computerChoice` is not defined. Please provide a runable example.

Comment: `you.innerHTML= my_score` does not _bind_  my_score to your HTML. It writes it once, that's it. Then you increment the Javascript variable, but don't update the HTML accordingly so the change is not visible.

Comment: @JeremyThille what do I have to do to fix that?

Comment: Repeat `you.innerHTML= my_score` every time `my_score` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are assigning the value outside the event handler function that code does not get executed when click happens (instead those code is executed on page load with the initial value). You have to update the HTML inside the event handler function.

Also I will suggest you to use `innerText` or `textContent` if the text is plain text (not htmlString).

Try the following:

```
var my_score = 0; 
var pc_score = 0;
const you = document.getElementById("You");
const computer = document.getElementById("Computer");
document.getElementById("scissors").addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    playerChoice=scissors;
    computerSelection();
    if (computerChoice == "rock"){
        results.textContent = "It is a loss";
        pc_score++;
    } else if (computerChoice == "paper"){
        results.textContent = "It is a win";
        my_score++;
    }else if (computerChoice=="scissors"){
        results.textContent = "It is a tie";
    }
    you.textContent = my_score;
    computer.textContent = pc_score;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the score variables, but not the innerHTML's of the elements showing that score. There surely is a better/cleaner way to do this, but just call `computer.innerHTML=pc_score` and `you.innerHTML= my_score` again after changing the value

Comment: Changing what value?